# How change the header labels TYPO3 7 LTS fluid_styled_content

Tags: label, typo3, backend, fluid, fluid-styled-content

I use `TYPO3 7.6.2 LTS`with the new `fluid_styled_content`. It's brilliant! Very easy to change the header types or upload elements or text/image stuff ...

But how can I change the Labels at Backend-TCA for the Header element f.e. Is it still over TSconfig or a locallang-file? And where it is?

And how can I disable some headlines. I only use Layout 1-3. If I found this, i'll never go back to `css_styled_content`..

Thanks for your advice.

[image: header backend typo3 change labels]

The old way was like this  TSconfig ..

```
    TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.altLabels {
    1 = H2 rot
    2 = Grafische Ueberschrift
    3 = Versteckt (CSS)
    4 = Nicht ausgeben
}
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.removeItems = 5,6,7,8,9,10,100
```

And TS setup

```
lib.stdheader = CASE
lib.stdheader {
   key.field = header_layout ..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing should have changed within TSconfig ... tested it ... works like a charm.

The frontend rendering of the header is not defined via TS any more (mostly), but via partials. Checkout the path settings in the TypoScript of `lib.fluidContent`. You can overwrite the default templates, partials and layout with your own fluid templates.

Comment: I'm sorry -...  I don't try it out first - my fault. Thanks, yes it works with `TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.altLabels ` and `TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.removeItems` like before.